# How to call extension code from my chrome.tabs.executeScript code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I've looked around in the google documnetation and/or this website for a while now, and I have found answers seemingly fit, but they don't work for me and I'm guessing maybe it is because I'm running my content script from execute script and not from background.

Here's what I'm trying to do: I've a extension that has a popup javascript that injects a code using executeScript inside popup.js, that code returns either true or false (I tried using a call back function to receive the returning value but the returning value was an empty array instead of true or false).

The second method I've tried using was using onMessage and addListener onMessage in the background page that never managed to catch an event.. and thus didn't work for me.
My code below:

popup.js

```
$('#btnGetHtml').click(function () {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery-3.1.1.js" });
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{
                code:"*Ajax call with the success function evaluating a value and closing.*" }, function(hasSucceeded){
            var temp = hasSucceeded; /*Here value is an empty array.*/  });

});
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
        chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
            conditions: [
                new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
                    pageUrl: { urlContains: 'linkedin.com/in' }
                })
            ],
            actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
        }]);
    });
});
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(result,sender,sendResponse){
       if (result == 'ok'){
           window.location.href='SuccessfullyAdded.html';
           }
       else{
           window.location.href='ErrorEncountered.html';
       }        
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Add LinkedIn Profile to HRMS",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "description": "תוסף למערכת הגיוס Hunter HRMS המאפשר לחפש מועמדים ברשת ה LinkedIn ולפתוח אותם בלחיצת כפתור במערכת הגיוס. מקור Sourcing ייחודי למערכת הגיוס.",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/icon32.png",
    "default_title": "Add LinkedIn Profile To Hunter HRMS (by NilooSoft)",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js" : ["getToken.js"],
        "run_at":"document_end"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>",
    "cookies",
    "declarativeContent",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "icons" : {
    "48" : "images/icon32.png",
    "128" : "images/icon32.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

What I am trying to do(Maybe is possible without tempering with calls between scripts) is change the extension html from one html to another based on the response from the content script.

Rest of the code is just htmls with a single button function, no extra logic.

Comment: Remove `return` from the injected code. It's not needed: the last evaluated expression is automatically transferred ([an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42335748) I wrote recently)

Comment: Removed the return, I still get an empty array from the call back. and when i try passing messages, I still don't receive the response in background.js.

Comment: Edited what I am doing exactly, not quite just a value from the DOM.

Comment: Ahem... Now you're using an asynchronous ajax in the injected code which won't return anything immediately, of course. So you'll need messaging. However, I don't understand why you do ajax in the injected code instead of doing it in the background? Also where is that `bg.js` declared? This is a very misleading name.

Comment: I meant background.js, as for the asynchronous, I have to do it as a content script since I need access to the tab's dom before I make the call.

Comment: Well, you can extract the info from DOM, leave it as a last expression of the injected code, then use it in the executeScript callback. Seems much simpler. Also, are you trying to navigate the background page's `window.location.href`? Won't work.

Comment: Ended up using messages and it worked, I sent the message to popup.js and from there changed the location.href to another html and that did it.  Thanks a lot!